# Angular 2 calling function from one component to another

Tags: angular, ionic2

How do i call a function from one component to another component using Angular 2. I have a function called, '**deleteAccount()**' inside parent component. but i want to call it from child component.

I tried using @viewChild but i am getting error saying, 
*Cannot read property 'deleteAccount' of undefined*

I have a template,

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-grid>  
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col width-50>
              <strong>BankName:</strong>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-50>
              syndicate
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
        <button ion-button item-right (click)="presentPopover($event, acclist)">
          <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item>
```

And the ts file,

```
     import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
     import { NavController, Events, PopoverController, ViewController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
     @Component({
        templateUrl: 'build/pages/addaccount/accountlistview.html'         
     })
     export class accountListView {
         constructor(
          private popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
          public viewCtrl: ViewController,
          public navParams: NavParams
          ) {

          }

          presentPopover(event, item) {
           let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, {"selectedItem": item});
           popover.present({
           ev: event
        });
      } 

      deleteAccount(item){

      }

      }

    @Component({
     template: `
       <ion-list>
         <button ion-item (click)="accountRemoveConfirm()">Delete</button>
       </ion-list>
      `
})
class PopoverPage {
  selectedAccObj = {};
  @ViewChild(accountListView) childcmp:accountListView;
  constructor(
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController
    ){
     this.selectedAccObj = navParams.get('selectedItem');
   }

  accountRemoveConfirm() {
    this.childcmp.deleteAccount(this.selectedAccObj);
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();  
   }
}
```

Comment: Well for that you user service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: EventEmitter with Output is the best way to pass command from child to parent.

Comment: @mehari, Could you please give the example

Comment: could you show me your accountlistview template

Comment: @vishnu I don't understand which one is child which one is parent. please specify the selector that I can understand.

Comment: @mehari, could u please check the updated code. here accountListView is parent

Comment: @vishnu Ok if that is the case, I can't see the 'popoverpage' selector in side accountListView(parent). There is no selector on the first place so this would not't work.  I am not sure if things are different on ionic, but on angular you need selector for every component.

Comment: Here is the component reference about types of interaction between angular components [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)